# What defines the specific enthalpy of atomization?

Tags: enthalpy

1 mol of $\ce{F2}$ is turned into $\ce{2F}$ (atoms).

Is this the specific enthalpy of atomization, or two times that?

Answer (score 1):

[ChemGuide](http://www.chemguide.co.uk/physical/energetics/lattice.html) says that 'The standard atomisation enthalpy is the enthalpy change when 1 mole of gaseous atoms is **formed** from the element in its standard state.'

For example,
\begin{array}{rc}
\ce{1/2 Cl2 (g) -> Cl (g)} & \Delta H_{a}^{0} = +122~\mathrm{kJ/mol} \\
\ce{1/2 Br2 (l) -> Br (g)} & \Delta H_{a}^{0} = +112~\mathrm{kJ/mol} \\
\ce{Na (s) -> Na (g)} & \Delta H_{a}^{0} = +107~\mathrm{kJ/mol}
\end{array}

Answer (score -2):

Enthalpy of atomisation is energy required to break 1 mole of E-E bonds.

Eg: $\ce{1 F2 -> 2 F}$ .............................$\Delta H_{atomisation}$